# Are "hence" and "thus" synonyms?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

I can't really see any difference in meaning between "hence" and "thus". To me they seem to be interchangeable, in every context I've encountered either of them the other one would have also fitted. So, are they truly synonyms?

Comment: The difference in usage is explained here: https://painintheenglish.com/case/4452/

Comment: Originally, ***hence*** was equivalent to ***away from here*** (as with ***thence** = ...from **there***, ***whence** = ...from **where***, etc.). That literal (locational) usage is fairly dated / literary today, but some people would still use ***hence*** to mean ***henceforth*** (from this/that time onward), and you can't substitute ***thus*** where it has that sense. Personally, I'd advise learners to stick with ***so***, and not bother learning how to use ***hence*** or ***thus*** at all (you might have to *read / hear* them, but you shouldn't really need to *use* them often, if at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither "hence" or "thus" are very often used except in mathematical proofs.  In that context they are pretty similar in meaning:

Hence: following from the preceding ...

Thus: it follows that...

"Hence" would start a sentence, and you sometimes see it in the form "Hence or otherwise" (meaning you should use the previous calculation, but you don't have to)

In non-mathematical use, hence can mean "from here", ("The station is five miles hence") But this is pretty rare.

If you are just speaking, or writing in non-mathematical way, then "so" is much more common.

> It's getting cold (thus?) (hence??) so you should take a coat.

Comment: As a mathematician I use "thus" and "hence" regularly. I have always understood the word "thus" to be more akin to "like this", as in "by use of this technique". "Hence" does indeed have the force of "from here".